# How to obtain access token for azure analysis services rest api (python)

Tags: azure, python, entra-id

I'm trying to refresh Azure Analysys tables using rest api (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/analysis-services/analysis-services-async-refresh) and python. I've created a user with server admin role and an azure ad application with owner role, but rest api seams to be rejecting the access tokens. How can I assign the necessary rights or what I do incorrect. I'm trying to access Analysis Services for example like this:

```
import adal

tenant_id = '...'
authentication_endpoint = f'https://login.windows.net/{tenant_id}'
resource  = 'https://westeurope.asazure.windows.net/'
client_id = '...'
client_secret = '...'
# get an Azure access token using the adal library
context = adal.AuthenticationContext(authentication_endpoint)
token_response = context.acquire_token_with_client_credentials(resource, client_id, client_secret)

access_token = token_response.get('accessToken')
print(access_token)

#####################################################

import json
import requests

location = 'westeurope'
server_name = '...'
model = '...'

url = f'https://{location}.asazure.windows.net/servers/{server_name}/models/{model}/refreshes'
table = '...'
objects = [ dict(table=table) ]
data = dict(
    type = 'Full',
    # CommitMode = 'transactional',
    # MaxParallelism = 2,
    RetryCount = 2,
    Objects = objects,
)
headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'Authorization': f'Bearer {access_token}',
}

response = requests.post(url=url, headers=headers, data = json.dumps(data))
print(response.text)
print(response.status_code)
```

The response is like this:

```
{"code":"Unauthorized","subCode":0,"message":"An internal error occurred.","timeStamp":"...","httpStatusCode":400,"details":[{"code":"RootActivityId","message":"..."},{"code":"Param1","message":"asazure://asazureweu3-westeurope.asazure.windows.net/..."}]}
400
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To call the `refreshes` API the service principal must have admin permissions in SSAS. This is not accomplished through the Azure portal but through SQL Server Management Studio as described [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/automation-of-azure-analysis-services-with-service-principals-and-powershell/).

> Once the service principal is created, its application ID can be
>   assigned permissions in the Azure Analysis Services server or model
>   roles using the following syntax. The example below adds a service
>   principal to the server administrators group in SSMS.
>
> `app:<app
>   guid>@<tenant guid>`
>
> [image: server admin in SSMS]